# A possibly elementary algebraic inequality

Tags: inequality, polynomials, radicals, substitution, symmetric-polynomials

First, the problem: let $a,\ b,\ c > 0$ be such that $abc = 1$. Prove that
$$\sum_{cyc} (a^2 - 2bc + 1) \ge 0$$

Some background: I was solving a competition inequality by playing around with possible identities/other inequalities that could lead to a solution. Essentially, I was looking for possible bounds that might help and then I was checking them numerically. So, I have verified the validity of the above inequality numerically. However, I have no idea how to actually prove it. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a^2=x^3$, $b^2=y^3$ and $c^2=z^3$.

Hence, $xyz=1$ and by Schur and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2-2bc+1)=\sum_{cyc}(x^3-2\sqrt{x^3y^3}+xyz)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(x^3-x^2y-x^2z+xyz)+\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+xy^2-2\sqrt{x^3y^3})\geq0.$$

Comment: Which is the motivation behind this solution?

Comment: Mike, the expression $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+1)$ recalls Schur and it turned out.